# How filter in a view

Tags: angularjs

i have this Code in my view

```
<div ng-repeat="config in configs">
     <div ng-repeat="test in tests ">
          <a href="#"> {{test[config.Name]}}</a></li>
     </div>
</div>
```

it works fine. But how can I filter test?

```
<div ng-repeat="test in Tests | filter:{[config.Name]:'Test'} ">
```

dont work. How can I filter the column config.Name?

Thanks for your Help

Stefan

Comment: Show us your `JSON` so we can see how to get the right bits of data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add that function to your controller:

```
$scope.createFilter = function(property, value) {
    var result = {};
    result[property] = value;
    return result;
};
```

and use it in the view:

```
<div ng-repeat="test in Tests | filter: createFilter(config.Name, 'Test')">
```

Comment: Thanks this was the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I hope that could help you:

JS :

```
$scope.conf = [];
$scope.conf.Name = 'Test';
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="config in configs | filter:conf:strict">
     <div ng-repeat="test in tests ">
          <a href="#"> {{test[config.Name]}}</a></li>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a tricky one, but if you put the filter value in a variable first that might work?

```
<div ng-repeat="config in configs" ng-init="$filter = {}; $filter[config.Name] = 'Test'}">
     <div ng-repeat="test in tests | filter : $filter">
          <a href="#"> {{test[config.Name]}}</a></li>
     </div>
</div>
```